# Match data tables in 2 sheets & pull data from column in 2nd sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to pull the data from a column if it matches the data of 2 cells in a table in sheet 1 & data in a table in sheet 2. For example, if c2 & d2 in sheet 1 matches the cells in column b & c on sheet 2 then pull data that is in cell of column f. The tables do have headings.

Comment: show an example

Comment: Parish Name City Families
St. Mary Parish Aleppo 78
St. Joseph Parish Andale 448
St. Vincent De Paul Parish Andover 1118
Sacred Heart Parish Arkansas City 338
St. Joseph Parish Arma 103
St. James Parish Augusta 482
St. Joseph Parish Baxter Springs 28
Holy Name of Jesus Parish Bushton 57

Answer (score 1):

```
Column B                     Column C            Column F
Parish Name                   City              Families
St. Mary Parish               Aleppo                78
St. Joseph Parish             Andale                448
St. Vincent de Paul Parish    Andover               1118
Sacred Heart Parish           Arkansas City         338
St. Joseph Parish             Arma                  103
St. James Parish              Augusta               482
St. Joseph Parish             Baxter Springs        28
Holy Name of Jesus Parish     Bushton               57
```

The above are in sheet2
in sheet1 if in B2 you have the Parish Name
and in C2 you have the City
in D2 write this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$F$2:$F$9,MATCH(Sheet1!C2&Sheet1!D2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$9&Sheet2!$C$2:$C$9,0)),"")
```

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just Enter it is an array Formula
change B2:B9 and C2:C9 to correspond the last Row in your Data and keep $ for fixed references and you will have the Families